# Namespace 'Handsontable' has no exported member '_editors'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, handsontable

I am trying to install handsOnTable with Vue 2 project using npm as per the documentation but the build is failing with the following error:

> ERROR in /node_modules/@handsontable/vue/types.d.ts(56,73):
> 56:73 Namespace 'Handsontable' has no exported member '_editors'.
> 54 | declare type ClassMethods = Pick<T, NotOriginalValueProp>;
> 55 | declare type ClassFields = Pick<T, ClassFieldKey>;
> 56 | export interface BaseVueEditorMethods extends ClassMethods<Handsontable._editors.Base> {
> |                                                                         ^
> 57 | }
> 58 | export interface BaseVueEditorFields extends ClassFields<Handsontable._editors.Base> {
> 59 | }

The project has Vue version `^2.6.14`, typescript version `~3.9.3` and handsOnTable vue version `^11.1.0`.

Answer (score 1):

It is said that

> Starting with Handsontable 11.0.0, the React wrapper, the Angular
> wrapper, and the Vue wrapper support modularization.

so you need to either register the editor you want to use or use the global method called `registerAllModules()` (it has to be imported before using).

At this is only one step out of 4. They are explained in the migration guide at https://handsontable.com/docs/migration-from-10.0-to-11.0/#typescript-definitions-files